# Django - Populating a database for test purposes

Tags: python, database, django

I need to populate my database with a bunch of dummy entries (around 200+) so that I can test the admin interface I've made and I was wondering if there was a better way to do it. I spent the better part of my day yesterday trying to fill it in by hand (i.e by wrapping stuff like this my_model(title="asdfasdf", field2="laksdj"...) in a bunch of "for x in range(0,200):" loops) and gave up because it didn't work the way I expected it to. I think [this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#topics-serialization) is what I need to use, but don't you need to have (existing) data in the database for this to work?

Comment: You don't want to serialize. You want to create initial data by running in the shell, saving the instances, and then exporting the database to a fixture in a format like json using loaddata: `python manage.py dumpdata --format=json --indent=4 appname` @Matthew Schinckel is closest on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this app

[https://github.com/aerosol/django-dilla/](https://github.com/aerosol/django-dilla)

Let's say you wrote your blog application (oh yeah, your favorite!) in Django. Unit tests went fine, and everything runs extremely fast, even those ORM-generated ultra-long queries. You've added several categorized posts and it's still stable as a rock. You're quite sure the app is efficient and ready to for live deployment. Right? Wrong.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Eeyore: your reply won't let me sleep.

Answer (score 6):

You can use fixtures for this purpose, and the [loaddata](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs#loaddata-fixture-fixture) management command.

One approach is to do it like this.

1. Prepare your test database.
2. Use dumpdata to create JSON export of the database.
3. Put this in the `fixtures` directory of your application.
4. Write your unit tests to load this "fixture": https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.fixtures

Comment: I just had to add some details.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.fixtures

Answer (score 3):

Django [fixtures](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/fixtures/) provide a mechanism for importing data on `syncdb`.  However, doing this initial data propagation is often easier via Python code.  The technique you outline should work, either via syncdb or a management command.  For instance, via syncdb, in `my_app/management.py`:

```
def init_data(sender, **kwargs):
    for i in range(1000):
        MyModel(number=i).save()

signals.post_syncdb.connect(init_data)
```

Or, in a [management command](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) in `myapp/management/commands/my_command.py`:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

from models import MyModel

class MyCommand(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if len(args) > 0:
            raise CommandError('need exactly zero arguments')

        for i in range(1000):
            MyModel(number=i).save()
```

You can then export this data to a fixture, or continue importing using the management command.  If you choose to continue to use the `syncdb` signal, you'll want to conditionally run the `init_data` function to prevent the data getting imported on subsequent `syncdb` calls.  When a fixture isn't sufficient, I personally like to do both: create a management command to import data, but have the first `syncdb` invocation do the import automatically.  That way, deployment is more automated but I can still easily make modifications to the initial data and re-run the import.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you require any serialization. As long as you have setup your Django settings.py file to point to your test database, populating a test database should be nothing more than saving models.

```
for x in range(0, 200):
    m = my_model(title=random_title(), field2=random_string(), ...)
    m.save()
```

There are better ways to do this, but if you want a quick test set, this is the way to go.

Comment: And you are running in the context of the shell, right? `python manage.py shell`

Answer (score 0):

The app recommended by the accepted answer is no longer being maintained however django-seed can be used as a replacement:

https://github.com/brobin/django-seed

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [django-autofixtures](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-autofixture) to you. I tried both django_seed and django-autofixtures, but django_seed has a lot of issues with unique keys.
django-autofixtures takes care of unique, primary and other db constraints while filling up the database